# Mutability/Immutability state variables in viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I wanted to know what is the difference between the two approaches for settings values in the viewmodels:

Approach one is using function to set the new value to the variable. The second approach is using the setter to set the value to the variable.

I know it is not recommended to expose mutable variables to the view but the execution is the same if we call the function or set the variable in the views.

```
A: 

``
class SampleViewModel(): ViewModel {
  
  private val _title = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val title: LiveData<String>
    get() = _title
  
  // Setting the title
  fun setTitle(newTitle: String) {
    _title.value = newTitle 
  }
  
}
```

B:

```
class SampleViewModel(): ViewModel {
  
  private val _title = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val title: LiveData<String>
    get() = _title
  
  
  // Setting the title
  var setTitle: String
    set(value) = {
      field = value 
      _title.value = value
    }
  
}
```

Any input is appreciated.

I tried both approaches and it is working fine on both cases.

Comment: The syntax is a little confusing e.g. how is it possible that `title: String` returns `MutableLiveData` in its `get` method? Please consider refactoring your code which user can understand your problem perfectly.

Comment: @mohammadfakhraee sorry I forgot to add the LiveData before the String keyword.

Comment: So as I  see now, both approaches are overally the same. But the main difference between these approaches is that you are holding two values for your `title` property in second approach. One for `_title.value` and one for `setTitle`.

Comment: And other difference is that in second approach, `setTitle` variable has to be instantiated which may not be good for the `LiveData` (consider a situation in which you dont need to hold an initial value for title)

Comment: @mohammadfakhraee thanks you are totally right. Sometimes we don't want to set a value initially in that case the A approach works better.